Resolving a circular dependency in an android studio application and an external unityLibrary
I am working on an android studio project which has a small unity game integrated into it, which is achieved by exporting it from unity and importing it as a module in android studio. I've gotten to the point where I can export the build from unity and have it run in the app, and can properly communicate between both using the following scripts in Unity,
private AndroidJavaObject activity;
public TextMeshProUGUI text;
private void Start()
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    activity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

}

public void SendUnityChatbotQuery(string input)
{       
    activity.Call("PerformActionAndReturnResult", text.text);
}

public void RecieveQueryResult(string result)
{
    Debug.Log(result);
}

and the relevant methods which are currently in my UnityPlayerActivity class in android studio.
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity implements IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents
{
    public void PerformActionAndReturnResult(String output) {
    
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidAPI", "RecieveQueryResult", output);
    }
    
}

However, the way I have the project set up has made it impossible for me to use classes from the app in the UnityPlayerActivity. Currently I have the project laid out as
App

manifests
java

com

group

application

DashboardActivity
OpenAiAssistant









unityLibrary

manifests
java

com

unity3d

player

UnityPlayerActivity









My build.gradle.kts for the app has a dependency set on this library so that I can open it within the DashboardActivity
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":unityLibrary")))

With this setup I can import the unity player package and properly launch up the game from a custom activity in android studio.
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
// Can properly import this activity here
Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button); // Ensure this ID matches your XML
    playButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("scanned_item", "INSERT JSON HERE");

        startActivity(intent);
    });

but issues arise when I want to do it the other way round.
In my UnityPlayerActivity class I want to change the simple implementation I had before into one that uses a class present in the android app to take the input and return something, but I don't have access to it and can't just import the class as I would have hoped to.
public void PerformActionAndReturnResult(String output) {
   OpenAIAssistant assistant = new OpenAIAssistant();
// OpenAIAssistant isn't recognised - Can't resolve symbol
    assistant.createThreadAndRun(userMessage, new OpenAIAssistant.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {                
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidAPI", "RecieveQueryResult", result);
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            // Handle error

        }
    });
}

I want to be able to use this custom class in my unity player activity, but I don't know how to go about it without introducing this circular dependency.
